# MS Access: Add attachment to record from Form field using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, attachment, ms-access-forms, ms-forms

I have a bounded form with property 'Data Entry = Yes' which has a multiple textboxes, and one field of type Attachment.

I have a "Save" button that prompts confirmation to save the record.

On the form I placed a checkbox labelled 'Includes training'.

If that checkbox is checked, I want to add to the same table, an additional record (other than the one added through the bounded form) with exactly the same information as the record inserted in the bounded form, except for one text field which will be different and defined in the VBA code.

I tried a `CurrentDB.Execute SQL` query but it does not work with the Attachment field type.

The [solution proposed in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/work-with-attachments-in-dao) doesn't apply to this case since I want to take the Attachment contained in the bounded Attachment field on the form and not from a path on disk.

I think something like the following could work, but when I test it, it saves the record from the bounded form, but not the additional one I want to add with the VBA code, AND it ends with the error:

> 424 Object Required

The VBA code:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim ctl As Control
    On Error GoTo Err_BeforeUpdate

    If Me.Dirty Then
      If MsgBox("Do you want to save the new record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
              "Save Record") = vbNo Then
         Me.Undo
         MsgBox "Changes discarded."
      Else
        If Me.checkbox.Value = True Then
        
            Set rsTable = db.OpenRecordset("Table")
            
            With rsTable
            .AddNew
            !TextField1 = Me.TextField1.Value
            !TextField2 = "My Own Text Field"
            !AttachmentField = Me.AttachmentField.Value 
            .Update
            .Bookmark = .LastModified
            End With

            MsgBox "Record was correctly saved."
        End If
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

EDIT:

So clearly this is not the right way to save a new record, but I need this record to be save AT THE SAME TIME (or just after) the one on the bounded form. I DON'T want the user to fill in another bounded form.

The reason for this is because what I am entering are language certification records, and there are certifications that are broader and include two levels.
Hence the checkbox signals "do you want to include the previous level as well?", if it is checked, then the PDF certificate uploaded will be valid both for level 1 and level 2.
All information will be the same except for the level name of the record.

I need these two to be separate records because I can also have them singularly and later I check conditions based on these individual language levels.

Comment: NOTE: You should never duplicate a record. If you have an attachment table whose Foreign ID is the table of this form, you can add as many attachments per record that you want. No duplication. Please study [Database Normalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description)

Comment: It is impractical to create a new table for all attachments since the number of cases where they are duplicated is an insignificant fraction of all the records.

Comment: If it happens once, it's a problem. Yet, that's not the reason for my recommendation. I'm recommending Database Normalization. It has many benefits. It's also a long subject with many conflicting opinions so it's best to do a lot of reading about the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by creating a separate bounded from that pops up when I hit "Save" on the original bounded form if the checkbox is checked. There the user has the choice on whether to upload the same document as the original bounded form, or a different one.

Answer (score 0):

To use an attachment field you to use the special methods `LoadFromFile` to put an attachment in the DB and `SaveFromFile` to get the attachment back out of the DB. It looks like you attempted to assign a string to an attachment field.

I don't see where `db` is defined. Did you mean `CurrentDb` ?

The other problem I see is that you are using [bang](https://bytecomb.com/the-bang-exclamation-operator-in-vba/) notation in a `With` block. Bang notation is a string lookup. If you want to call the item by name you would do so like this:

```
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table")
    .AddNew
    .Fields.Item("TextField1").Value = Me.TextField1.Value
    .Fields.Item("TextField2").Value = "My Own Text Field"
    .Fields.Item("AttachmentField").LoadFromFile Me.AttachmentField.FileName
    .Update
    .Bookmark = .LastModified
    .Close
End With
```

The name of those Items must be correct.

Comment: `With rs` ... `!Fieldname = foo` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Andre just because you can doesn't mean you should. There are many heated debates on the subject. I am in the "never use bang" camp. Solely because I would rather catch a problem at compile time then at run-time. Bang leads to more run-time errors because it can hide problems from you.

Comment: Wherever it's useful, I'm with you. But neither `!Feildname` nor `.Fields.Item("Feildname").Value` will catch a misspelled field name at compile time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! @HackSlash 's solution runs smoothly until the line .Fields.Item("AttachmentField").LoadFromFile Me.AttachmentField.Value where the long feared compile error appears: "Method or Data member not found" on the .Value property of AttachmentField. I quadrupled checked the field name spelling

Comment: Ok, `LoadFromFile` is expecting a string that is the path to a real file. So what is returned by `? Me.AttachmentField.Value` ? Is it a string? You might need to use `Me.AttachmentField.FileName` instead.

Comment: If you use the form to update the table for you, the AttachmentField would work automagically. You're only having problems because you didn't create you form object correctly and you are trying to force it to work with VBA.

Comment: Nothing is returned by `Me.AttachmentField.Value` because the property `.Value` doens't exist for this field type. FileName is also invalid. 
I have set up a bounded form correctly, I just need to save an additional record in the background: Read Edit in question.

Comment: Sorry I mispoke, FileName is a valid property but it doesn't comply with the file type of LoadFromFile

Comment: It is not set up properly. If you had a normalized database then you wouldn't be having this problem at all. It's a non-issue. You will have to do some debugging. Nobody can debug this for you.